# Python looks for SSL certificates in linux paths, but I'm using Windows: how to change?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, ssl-certificate

I have an installation of Python from the Anaconda environment. If I check where Python is looking for SSL certificates with the code below, I get weird results:

```py
import ssl
ssl.get_default_verify_paths()
```

The output is:

```
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/local/ssl/certs')
```

Which doesn't make much sense to me: Why are the paths in a "linux style"? I'm trying to do API requests with the `requests` package and I'm getting SSL errors.

How can I change the path variables?

How could I have prevented this in the first place (the Anaconda installation was not by me, though, but my employer's IT)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is necessarily something you did, but a default of the packages. Windows has its own cryptography API and doesnt use openssl. So the assumption was made that anyone using openssl would be on a mac or linux computer and the filepaths for the openssl paths was set accordingly. Not 100% sure that is the answer, but it seems probable.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, it doesn't solve my problem, though :) I thought it could be a common problem, but apparently not many people use python on windows (which I'm forced to do).